# Generate a sequence of numbers in Python

Tags: python, sequence

How can I generate the sequence of numbers "1,2,5,6,9,10......" and so until 100 in Python?
I even need the comma (',') included, but this is not the main problem.

The sequence: every number from 1..100, divisible by 4 with remainder 1 or 2.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Every number from 1,2,5,6,9,10... is divisible by 4 with remainder 1 or 2.

```
>>> ','.join(str(i) for i in xrange(100) if i % 4 in (1,2))
'1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,...'
```

Comment: A Python 3 version is supplied by Oleh Prypin

Answer (score 20):

```
>>> ','.join('{},{}'.format(i, i + 1) for i in range(1, 100, 4))
'1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18,21,22,25,26,29,30,33,34,37,38,41,42,45,46,49,50,53,54,57,58,61,62,65,66,69,70,73,74,77,78,81,82,85,86,89,90,93,94,97,98'
```

That was a quick and quite dirty solution.

Now, for a solution that is suitable for different kinds of progression problems:

```
def deltas():
    while True:
        yield 1
        yield 3
def numbers(start, deltas, max):
    i = start
    while i <= max:
        yield i
        i += next(deltas)
print(','.join(str(i) for i in numbers(1, deltas(), 100)))
```

And here are similar ideas implemented using [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
from itertools import cycle, takewhile, accumulate, chain

def numbers(start, deltas, max):
    deltas = cycle(deltas)
    numbers = accumulate(chain([start], deltas))
    return takewhile(lambda x: x <= max, numbers)

print(','.join(str(x) for x in numbers(1, [1, 3], 100)))
```

Comment: One liner, thanks! That's really nice! Initially I though something of this                                                                'odd = []'
'even = []'
'for c in range(0,100):'
    'if c%2==0:'
        'odd.append(c)'

'for c in range(0,100):'
    'if c%2==1:'
        'even.append(c)'

'for c in range(0, 50):'
    'if c % 2 == 0:'
        'print(even[c],end=",")'
    'else:'
        'print(odd[c],end=",")'                                             Yeah, I'm a newcomer. But I knew there must be better ways! Thanks guys!

Comment: Further description of the final function would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15):

Includes some guessing on the exact sequence you are expecting:

```
>>> l = list(range(1, 100, 4)) + list(range(2, 100, 4))
>>> l.sort()
>>> ','.join(map(str, l))
'1,2,5,6,9,10,13,14,17,18,21,22,25,26,29,30,33,34,37,38,41,42,45,46,49,50,53,54,57,58,61,62,65,66,69,70,73,74,77,78,81,82,85,86,89,90,93,94,97,98'
```

As one-liner:

```
>>> ','.join(map(str, sorted(list(range(1, 100, 4))) + list(range(2, 100, 4))))
```

*(btw. this is Python 3 compatible)*

Answer (score 2):

This works by exploiting the % properties of the list rather than the increments.

```
for num in range(1,100):
    if num % 4 == 1 or num % 4 ==2:
        n.append(num)
        continue
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

using numpy and list comprehension you can do the

```
import numpy as np
[num for num in np.arange(1,101) if (num%4 == 1 or num%4 == 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I've guessed the pattern correctly (alternating increments of 1 and 3), this should produce the desired result:

```
def sequence():
    res = []
    diff = 1
    x = 1
    while x <= 100:
        res.append(x)
        x += diff
        diff = 3 if diff == 1 else 1
    return ', '.join(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your sequence alternates increments between 1 and 3

```
numbers = [1]
while numbers[-1] < 100:
    numbers.append(numbers[-1] + 1)
    numbers.append(numbers[-1] + 3)

print ', '.join(map(str, numbers))
```

This could be easier to modify if your sequence is different but I think poke or BlaXpirit are nicer answers than mine.

Answer (score -1):

Write a function that takes a number as an argument and prints the Fibonacci series till that number

```
def Series(n):  
    a = 0  
    b = 1  
    print(a)  
    print(b)  
    S = 0  
    for i in range(0,n):  
        if S <= n-1:  
            S = a + b  
            print(S)  
            a = b  
            b = S
```

Answer (score -2):

In python 3.1 you can produce a list in a way

```
     lst=list(range(100))
     for i in range(100)
        print (lst[i],',',end='')
```

In python 2.7 you can do it as

```
     lst=range(100)
     for i in range(100)
        print lst[i]+','
```

Comment: Why are you iterating over a separate range object? You should just iterate over the list items.